# can not find the solution to my "addEventListener" function

Tags: javascript, html

I am stuck on problem where I try to utilies the addEventListener.
I did try to find solutions on the web but I think my knowledge is to limited to pick the suitable answer.

What I tried is to invoke a function "*addFile()*" when a key is pressed in this example enter(13) unfortunatly nothing happens. I could add the onkeypress attribute to the input *"add-file"* with a slightly edited *addFileOnKeyEvent(event)* but I'm trying to understand what is wrong with my eventListener.

I hope you could follow my explanation, as this is my first question. :)

```js
function addFile() {
  var x = document.getElementById("add-file").value;
  x = x + ".xml";
  var lbl = document.createElement("label");
  var node = document.createTextNode(x);
  lbl.appendChild(node);

  var element = document.getElementById("appendable");
  element.appendChild(lbl);
}

function addFileOnKeyEvent(event) {
  var evt = event.keyCode;
  var textField = document.getElementById("add-file").addEventListener("keypress", function() {
    if (evt == 13) {
      addFile();
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<label>Dateien</label>
<input id="add-file" type="text" onclick="this.select();">
<button type="submit" onclick="addFile()">Hinzufügen</button>
<div class="data-display">
  <span id="appendable"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you calling `addFileOnKeyEvent()` anywhere? I don't see it in your provided code.

Comment: Passing `event` inside `addFileOnKeyEvent()` doesn't make much sense. It must be inside the `addEventListener` callback function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, `addFileOnKeyEvent()` is never called before anywhere. So you must call it when you try to add file. Or you must bind the event to the text field by default.

Also need not pass event object to `addFileOnKeyEvent().` The event must be captured in the addEventListener callback function.

```js
function addFile() {
  var x = document.getElementById("add-file").value;
  x = x + ".xml";
  var lbl = document.createElement("label");
  var node = document.createTextNode(x);
  lbl.appendChild(node);

  var element = document.getElementById("appendable");
  element.appendChild(lbl);
}

function addFileOnKeyEvent() {
  document.getElementById("add-file").addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
    var evt = event.keyCode;
    if (evt == 13) {
      addFile();
    }
  });
}
// call the function here
addFileOnKeyEvent();

   // else just put the event handler part alone. The function is unnecessary here.
```

```html
<label>Dateien</label>
<input id="add-file" type="text" onclick="this.select();">
<button type="submit" onclick="addFile()">Hinzufügen</button>
<div class="data-display">
  <span id="appendable"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: This helped me alot, I had the misconception that by writing the _function_ with the eventListener would lead to my goal.
As if it would sense the keypress magically.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how events work. Try this...

```
document.getElementById("add-file").addEventListener(
    "keypress", 
    function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            addFile();
        }
    });
```

Instead of...

```
function addFileOnKeyEvent(event) {
  var evt = event.keyCode;
  var textField = document.getElementById("add-file").addEventListener("keypress", function() {
    if (evt == 13) {
      addFile();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer also helped me to shorten my code.